# Python: Multiprocessing code is very slow

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pymongo

I am pulling `.8` million of records in one go(this is one time process) from `mongodb` using `pymongo` and performing some operation over it .

My code look as below.

```
    proc = []
    for rec in cursor: # cursor has .8 million rows 
            print cnt
            cnt = cnt + 1
            url =  rec['urlk']
            mkptid = rec['mkptid']
            cii = rec['cii']

            #self.process_single_layer(url, mkptid, cii)


            proc = Process(target=self.process_single_layer, args=(url, mkptid, cii))
            procs.append(proc)
            proc.start()

             # complete the processes
    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
```

`process_single_layer`  is a function which is basically downloading `urls`.from cloud and storing locally.

Now the problem is downloading process is slow as it has to hit a url. And since records are huge to process 1k rows it is taking  6 minutes.

To reduce the time I wanted to implement `Multiprocessing`. But It is hard to see any difference with above code.

Please suggest me how can I improve the performance in this scenario.

Comment: I sure hope that's not the actual indentation of your program, otherwise you are joining each process after starting it, effectively running them in series and not parallel.

Comment: and the second bad part is that you are creating a `Process` for each row.

Comment: The code make no sense at all, maybe your identation is wrong? Anyway I suggest that you do some filtering in the db so you do not bring all records data but the one you want.

Comment: Actually my multiprocessing implementation is not correct .as it will add no value untill we make it parallel . But in this scenario I am not able to think how can I achieve parallelism

Comment: First, like other suggest that you need to join after all process started, otherwise your program is just series running. Second, did you want to run .8m process at same time. In your original code with the fix join condition, your program will generate .8m processes ...

Comment: Considering that you are dealing with network operation (URLs), you'd better look at Threading rather than Multiprocessing.

Comment: This is a classic job for asyncio. You can get non-blocking network operation with it. However, if you are using up all your download bandwidth for a single url, then I don't think you can speed it up.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to count all the rows in your file and then spawn a fixed number of processes (ideally matching the number of your processor cores), to which you feed via queues (one for each process) a number of rows equal to the division `total_number_of_rows / number_of_cores`. The idea behind this approach is that you split the processing of those rows between multiple processes, hence achieving parallelism.

A way to find out the number of cores dynamically is by doing:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
cores_count = mp.cpu_count()
```

A slight improvement that can be done by avoiding the initial rows count is by adding a row cyclically by creating the list of queues and then apply a cycle iterator on it.

A full example:

```
import queue
import multiprocessing as mp
import itertools as itools

cores_count = mp.cpu_count()


def dosomething(q):

    while True:

        try:
            row = q.get(timeout=5)
        except queue.Empty:
            break

    # ..do some processing here with the row

    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    processes
    queues = []

    # spawn the processes
    for i in range(cores_count):
        q = mp.Queue()
        queues.append(q)
        proc = Process(target=dosomething, args=(q,))
        processes.append(proc)

    queues_cycle = itools.cycle(queues)
    for row in cursor:
        q = next(queues_cycle)
        q.put(row)

    # do the join after spawning all the processes
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

Comment: This is correct if the processing is CPU-bound, but it seems like the OP's problem is that he is fetching URLs from the Internet - and that is going to be network bound.  He can afford to have *many* more threads than CPUs, because most of the threads will be blocked waiting for a network response.

Comment: The OP might be better off using some sort of message-based system so that no thread is blocked.  At the point he might well be better off staying single threaded (because multi-threaded is so hard to understand.

Comment: @MartinBonner ***"...because multi-threaded is so hard to understand..."*** is not really an argument. Using threading instead of multiprocessing is not a good idea for network operations as to why the threads run in a single process and the parallelization is virtual (they actually run each operation from each thread in turns), which means is not pure parallelism. I've done multiprocessing with network operations and to be honest I've got pretty good results compared to threading or simple-threading.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to use a pool in this scenario.

Queues are not necessary as you don't need to communicate between your spawned processes. We can use the `Pool.map` to distribute the workload.

`Pool.imap` or `Pool.imap_unordered` might be faster with a larger chunk size. (Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap) You can use the `Pool.starmap` if you want and get rid of tuple unpacking.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def process_single_layer(data):
    # unpack the tuple and do the processing
    url, mkptid, cii = data
    return "downloaded" + url

def get_urls():
    # replace this code: iterate over cursor and yield necessary data as a tuple
    for rec in range(8): 
            url =  "url:" + str(rec)
            mkptid = "mkptid:" + str(rec)
            cii = "cii:" + str(rec)
            yield (url, mkptid, cii)

#  you can come up with suitable process count based on the number of CPUs.
with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
    print(pool.map(process_single_layer, get_urls()))
```